# After successful post XHR request render it to a url not working

Tags: javascript, redirect, xmlhttprequest

I am creating a login page, I want to redirect to a URL after successful XHR post request.

```
function statusChangeCallback(){
      // if(response.status === 'connected'){
         console.log('Logged in and authenticated', $("#username").val(), $("#password").val());
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            console.log(xhr.response)
            $.cookie("access_token",JSON.parse(JSON.parse(xhr.response).data.user).token);
            {
              location.replace("https://localhost/executive.html");
          }}
        }
        xhr.open("POST", "https://localhost/api/login", false);
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ "password": $("#password").val(),"email":$("#username").val()}));
        // $.cookie('accessToken', FB.getAuthResponse() .
```

I am using `location.replace` but it's not working.

console output for `xhr.response`:

```
  {"error": false, "message": "User Data updated successfully", "data": {"user": "{\"_id\": \"5c274f4f4302725e08b839e6\", \"email\": \"demo@email.com\", \"password\": \"password\", \"token\": \"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImRlbWL1iVVScLFN46Tczg\", \"facebook_accesstoken\": \"EAADlFlUKzwcBAM4WYk2pusO3J4PH92TUM3z9lEeHZCb15BegHqC97NH0aTsH7bN9JMfiKDoTQbExqIKze3SigaryZCU6v3dhTW2zZB4aqPuhopMWTQ3Y0gie85VkeYAwNEGRTmHgJ3dw7iH5CYMmuAZDZD\", \"facebook_email\": \"apexian2013_ashwani@yahoo.com\", \"instagram_password\": \"P********\", \"instagram_username\": \"p**********\"}"}, "errors": null, "code": 200}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is a useless problem description. We know it's not working. Did you check the browser console? Any error messages? Nevermind: I'll bet it's due to calling `JSON.parse()`

Comment: i want to render to  "https://localhost/executive.html" after successful response

Comment: try alert('something') before location.replace check if is working.

Comment: @chris there is no error message!

Comment: What is `xhr.response?` Why are you trying to parse its `token`? Edit: `location.replace` should work perfectly fine, so it's never called in the first place.

Comment: @Bugfixer i am getting the xhr response in my console

Comment: So what is it? Can you add it to your question? And why is `location.replace` inside curly braces?

Comment: @ChrisG its not working even i remove the curly braces , and i am new to java script.

Comment: Please add the console output for `xhr.response` to your question. I'll bet $100 it's the JSON.parse() stuff that causes an error. I'm trying to create a `response` that can actually be parsed your way, and so far no luck.

Comment: @ChrisG i have edited my question with the added console output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186162/discussion-between-ashwini-kumar-jha-and-chris-g).